# Adding a ruler to the OpenStreetMap site?

Tags: openstreetmap

As a cyclist, I often need to measure the distance between two locations to have a rough idea.

The [OSM website](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) contains no ruler, and I was wondering if there were a way to add one, or if a similar site exists that does have one.

Answer (score 5):

"Sammys Fullscreen Map" does have a measure function on the left side:

http://www.sammyshp.de/fsmap/#9/48.5602/12.3061

more leaflet measure controls include (link to their demo pages at github)

- http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.MeasureControl/
- http://ljagis.github.io/leaflet-measure/
- http://jtreml.github.io/leaflet.measure/example.html

Comment: +1 http://www.Sammyshp.de/fsmap very nice site measure tool with distance between points and total distance, good for also measuring site boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy enough to create a new web map application that does what you need. I would start with the [OpenLayer's Measure Example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/measure.html) and change the base map and extent to be the area of interest.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try [BRouter web service](http://brouter.de/brouter-web/) which is specialized on bike routing.

Click on the map to define starting point and end/intermediate points, and you will get distances on real ways instantly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the very fast [Open Source Routing Machine](http://project-osrm.org/) for general routing with OSM data. Explicitly for bicyclists I'd recommend [OpenRouteService](http://openrouteservice.org/).

However, as far as I know ORS does not support worldwide coverage yet. Check the OSM wiki for more information (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRouteService respectively http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Open_Source_Routing_Machine).

For more routing engines/websites based on OpenStreetMap data check this [wiki
post](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing).